# Compile .kt files nested in folders with kotlinc

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, kotlinc

I want to use *kotlinc* to compile multiple files that are organized in folders, like in this minimal example:

[image]

*Main.kt* only calls *helper.kt* which contains

[image]

When I call: kotlinc *.kt -include-runtime -d Main.jar

I get the error

[image]

I guess the problem is that *.kt doesn't compile files nested in folders. How do I change that?
I didn't find a flag for it in the kotlinc documentation.

Comment: (Not done enough research to justify posting this as an answer…)  It's usually best to use a build tool such as Gradle, Maven, or IntelliJ. If you really need to call `kotlinc` manually, I think you'll include all the .kt files. How you do that will depend upon your OS and/or shell; e.g. in zsh you could just use `kotlinc **/*.kt`; for general Unix-like shells you could do something like `find . -name '*.kt' | xargs kotlinc`.

Comment: I used Git Bash on windows for it, thanks for the idea